# Difficult matrix equation $A(x-x_0) + \alpha\left(\frac{\Sigma x}{\mu^\top x}\right) = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Let $x,x_0,\theta,\mu \in \mathbb{R}^n$ vectors, $\alpha \in\mathbb{R}$ a scalar, and $\Sigma, A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ Positive Semi-Definite matrices. Also, $\mu$ is a mean vector and $\Sigma$ is a covariance matrix of a Random Variable $Z$ (I don't know if this information may help). Is there a way to solve in closed form the following matrix equation for $x$?

\begin{equation}
A(x-x_0) + \alpha \left(\frac{\Sigma x}{\mu^\top x}\right) = 0. 
\end{equation}

**Main difficulty:** I find difficulties in handling the denominator. If the equation would have been simply

$$A(x-x_0) + \alpha \Sigma x = 0,$$ the solution would be $x = (A+\alpha\Sigma)^{-1}Ax_0$. I am looking for a similar solution for the first equation but the denominator complicates things and I don't know how to proceed.

**What I tried:**

\begin{aligned}
& \mu^TxA(x-x_0) + \alpha \Sigma x = 0
\\ &\mu^TxAx - \mu^TxAx_0 - \alpha \Sigma x = 0
\\ &\mu^TxA(x-x_0) = \alpha \Sigma x 
\end{aligned}

Is this way of proceeding correct? If yes, how is it possible to solve this matrix equation for $x$? I am not an expert in solving matrix equations and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Rearranging the equation to isolate $x$ on the LHS creates a usable iterative method, i.e.
$$x_+ = \left(\frac{\alpha A^{-1}\Sigma x}{\mu^Tx}\right) + x_0$$

Comment: Hi @greg, I know about iterative methods or other ways to solve this, this question is about closed-form solution of the equation, if it exists.

Comment: "Hence the solution is either $x = 0$, or an $x \in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $(\mu^TxA - \mu^Tx_0A - \alpha \Sigma) = 0$."



This conclusion is wrong. $Ax=0$ does not imply $A=0$ or $x=0$, but only $x\in\ker(A)$

Comment: There is an error in the 3rd line of your calculation, namely 
$$(\mu^Tx)Ax_0 \ne (\mu^Tx_0)Ax$$
Also, since the sign of the $\alpha$-term has been changed from that of the equation in the title, the iteration also requires a sign change 
$$x_{k+1} = x_0 - \left(\frac{\alpha A^{-1}\Sigma x_k}{\mu^Tx_k}\right)$$

Comment: That is true, however the $x$ in $\mu^Tx$ is different, it is a fully contracted _scalar_ quantity. The appearance of the sequence $[xA]$ should tell you that there is no product occurring between the $x$ and the $A$ as it doesn't make any sense dimensionally. The only valid rearrangements are (with parentheses added for clarity) the following  $$(\mu^Tx)(Ax_0) = (Ax_0)(\mu^Tx) = (Ax_0)(x^T\mu) = (x^T\mu) (Ax_0)$$Try it with a few random vectors and matrices and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Your latest edit still has an error in the third line. You **cannot** eliminate the $Ax_0$ term.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119014/discussion-between-apprentice-and-greg).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can provide some hints for the case where $A,\Sigma$ are strictly positive definite. This assumption guarantees us that both matrices are invertible; let us set henceforth $\lambda=\frac{\alpha}{\mu^T x}$. By multiplying on the right by $\Sigma^{-1}$ the problem transforms into the following one:

$$(B-\lambda I)x=B x_0~~,~~B=\Sigma^{-1}A$$

Of course $B x_0\neq 0$, since $B$ is itself positive definite. Now it is finally obvious that $B-\lambda I$ can only be singular for $\lambda $ in the set of eigenvalues of the matrix $B$ itself, in which case a solution does not exist. For all other values of the parameter a unique solution is guaranteed; if one uses the eigenvalue decomposition of $B=S\Lambda S^{-1}$ the solution is given by the relation

$$x=S(\Lambda-\lambda I)^{-1}S^{-1}Bx_0$$

This solution is naturally, a function of $\lambda$ itself, which can be written in the concise form
$$x=\sum_{k}\frac{v_k}{\lambda_k-\lambda}$$
where the sum is performed over the **distinct** eigenvalues of $B$ with the vectors $(v_k)_i=S_{ik}\sum_{lm}S^{-1}_{kl}B_{lm}(x_0)_{m}$ whenever all the eigenvalues have multiplicity 1 (but with trivial modifications if it's greater than 1-just take the limit of coinciding eigenvalues).

We are not done- $\lambda$ depends on $x$ itself and that imposes a constraint on the possible solutions. Dotting from the left with the vector $\mu$, we obtain the rational equation
$$\frac{\alpha}{\lambda}=\sum_{k}\frac{\mu^Tv_k}{\lambda_k-\lambda}$$
which generally has $n$ complex roots. However $\lambda$ is a real parameter. Is a solution guaranteed? It is only guaranteed for odd $n$, since the polynomial equation then is forced to have a real solution. A counterexample to this is given by the function
$$f(\lambda)=-\frac{1}{1-\lambda}+\frac{1}{2-\lambda}-\frac{3}{\lambda}$$
which has no real roots. However, it is true that there may be found a large enough value of $|\alpha|$ for which a real solution exists, regardless of the values of $n$ and the projections $\mu^T v_k$.

**EDIT**: I believe that this is as close algorithmically as one can get to a "closed form". The problem has certainly been reduced to a simpler one, but the impasse is obvious- we cannot solve arbitrary degree polynomial equations in closed form.

Comment: One should add that this is only a necessary condition, even if we solve $f(\lambda(x))=0$, it is not guaranteed that the $x$ obtained that way will be a solution to the original equation since the implication $x=y\implies \mu^T x = \mu^T y$ is generally not reversible.

Comment: Thanks. Can you have a look at my updated question? I made some progress.

Comment: @Hyperplane I think I disagree with your comment. $x(\lambda)$ is guaranteed to be a solution to the original system of equations for any value of the parameter $\lambda$ that is not an eigenvalue. The condition  $\lambda(\mu^T x)=\alpha$ selects out a few values (or none), which must then satisfy the original equation by the previous assertion.

Comment: Ah ok, I see it now. Assuming $\alpha=1$, solving the $\lambda$-equation yields $\mu^T x = \frac{1}{\lambda}$ which implies $x = \frac{1}{\lambda \mu^T \mu}\mu + \mu^\perp$. Then, after plugging $x$ back into the equation the orthogonal part is uniquely determined by $\mu^\perp = (\Lambda-\lambda I)^{-1}y - \frac{1}{\lambda \mu^T\mu}\mu$, which is always solvable as the RHS is orthogonal to $\mu$ by construction.

Comment: So I guess the take-away is that in this special problem the system of second degree polynomials in $k$ variables can always be reduced to a polynomial of degree $\le k$ in one variable.

Answer (score 2):

By multiplying with $(\mu^T x)$ we see that the equation is of the form of a system of second degree polynomials. These systems are generally not solvable "in closed form", since (1) higher degree polynomial systems can be reduced to second degree systems in more variables (2) polynomials of degree $\ge 5$ [cannot be solved "in closed form"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem). (cf. discussion on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/153436/can-you-efficiently-solve-a-system-of-quadratic-multivariate-polynomials)).

So you shouldn't expect a "closed form" solution. Depending on your use case, you can try two things:

1. Try solving particular instantiations of the systems using computer algebra packages such as [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html)
2. Use Numerical methods such as [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) or [fixed point iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration)

At the end of the day, the question you should always ask yourself is whether do you really need a "closed form" solution.

Comment: I need a closed-form solution since this problem is part of a larger problem in which a closed-form solution of this equation would provide an "easy" way to continue solving the bigger problem analytically.

Comment: @Apprentice, well, again the point I am trying to make is that generally when faced with non-linear equations one should not expect a nice "closed form" solution to exists. Of course sometimes it does and that's nice and all, but that's not the rule. Btw. I keep "closed form" in quotation marks because the notion of what constitutes a closed form solution is pretty arbitrary. In any case what I would suggest is looking first for things like existence and uniqueness. Then you can always continue your argument by simply calling $x^*$ the solution to the set of equations.

Comment: Thanks. Can you have a look at my updated question? I made some progress.

Answer (score 1):

To extend Hyperplane's comments about the definition of the term "closed-form", suppose you defined a function which, given the parameters $(A,\Sigma,\mu,x_0)$ computes the following iteration until it converges
$$\eqalign{
x_{k+1} &= x_0 - \left(\frac{\alpha A^{-1}\Sigma x_k}{\mu^Tx_k}\right) \\
x_* &= \lim_{k\to\infty} x_k\\
}$$
and returns the matrix
$$\eqalign{
B &= \frac{x_* x_0^T}{x_0^Tx_0}
}$$
This would allow you to write a concise solution to your problem in the desired form, i.e.
$$x = Bx_0$$
Would that meet your definition of "closed form"? If not, then why do you accept
$$\eqalign{Ax = b \quad\implies\quad x=A^+b}$$
as a closed form solution of an over-determined system of equations? If you peek inside the algorithm for the Moore-Penrose inverse you will see similar iterative techniques in use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The closed-form I had in mind would involve an explicit expression of $x$ in terms of $\mu,\Sigma,A$, so what you propose is not included in this definition.

Comment: Let me add that this iterative procedure may not converge; I have shown below with an explicit example that even when the matrices are invertible, there may be no solutions to the system- so this must mean that this procedure has no fixed point in some cases.

Comment: @DinosaurEgg I absolutely agree, the problem as posed may not have any solution, in which case the proposed iteration will fail to converge.

Comment: @Apprentice The algorithm also only depends on $\mu, \Sigma, A, x_0$. To point out one thing: if you are interested in, say, derivatives of the solution w.r.t. to these parameters, that can be achieved via implicit differentiation. Similarly other properties of the solution such as asymptotics may also be deductible without actually having a closed form solution.